# CoreAnimation memory issue with ARC

Tags: ios, memory, automatic-ref-counting

In my iPhone application utilizing ARC pushing certain view controllers leads to large memory allocations which are not released. Most of the Live Bytes have the header VM: CoreAnimation

[image]

I have tried wrapping various pieces of code, such as pushing the view controller, with @autoreleasepool { } but it doesn't make any difference. Setting the view controllers to nil once they are no longer needed also doesn't help.

Your help and advice will be much appreciated!

UPDATE

I realised that the timing of the memory allocations coincided with a detail view with a CorePlot chart being pushed from a table view. The detail view was also referenced in the table view's header file. One issue was that I was setting the detail view to nil and then reallocating it prior to it being pushed. If I instead initiate the detail view once only when the table view is first loaded, and then refresh its contents before each push, the memory allocation only happens once.

However, I have not been able to completely solve the issue as there is still a large memory allocation when the detail view is first pushed, which is never released.

Comment: ...are you generated the graphics context in a loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered that the memory issues were caused by the creation of new Core-Plot charts that were not releasing their memory when I attempted to deallocate them.

I managed to improve performance using this function when I try to deallocate the charts:

[graph removePlot:plot];

This has been sufficient to significantly improve the situation, although I am still struggling to get 100% memory release. From reading the Core Plot forums it appears I am not the only one to have experienced such issues...

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/coreplot-discuss/memory/coreplot-discuss/nWui9VjnMtQ/er2FO3o9syYJ

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you are using CoreGraphics framework for drawing something on view's, but you are not releasing coreGraphics object. CoreGraphics object is not released by ARC it must be retain/release manually.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I investigated but it wasn't the source of the issue